# How to query serialized data rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a mail model that is backed by a db table. Recipients is a serialized array that holds Contact id #'s and raw emails. I would like to be able to query to get all emails that were sent to a Contact. How do I do a find_by_recipients(includes contact.id)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 options

1. Remodel you data, extract serialized data to new tables/columns
2. Index your data using some search engine (SOLR probably, with sunspot_solr gem)
3. Use a nosql solution instead, MongoDB with mongo_mapper/mongoid preferably

Answer (score 0):

You can't really query the internals of serialized data. Either you should figure out a different way of storing the data, or fetch all of the records and iterate through them in some way or another with Ruby (exactly how you do this is up to you, based on your style). 
Warning: the latter would be very slow if there are many records.